# How to manually trigger a `change` event on a Backbone model?

Tags: backbone.js

I am trying to manually trigger a `change` event on a Backbone model that belongs to a collection. Here is a minimal example: ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9mh5em4e/1/))

```
var PersonModel = Backbone.Model.extend({});

var PersonCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: PersonModel
});

var person = new PersonModel({ name: 'Spike' });
var people = new PersonCollection([person]);

person.trigger('change'); // throws error
console.log('triggered event successfully');
```

But I get the following error when I trigger the event: (In JSFiddle, open the Javascipt Console to see the full error)

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'previousAttributes' of undefined
```

How can I fix this?

(The reason I'm doing this is that in the actual code the model has a collection -- for example `person.things = new ThingCollection();` -- and I want to manually trigger the `change` event on `person` when its collection changes)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `change` event is expected to have parameters, as described in the [event catalog](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-catalog).

The event should have `(model, options)` as parameters, where model is the model itself and options is the options object used with `set`. I can't recall off the top of my head if options is optional.

In your case, since you're just triggering the event manually you'll have to provide those arguments. The error your seeing is from some other code trying to access `model.previousAttributes` with model being undefined.

TL;DR:

```
person.trigger('change', person, {});
```

And you might be able to omit the `{}`.